# What is the Visual Studio 2015 command to display the Team Explorer Build window

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the Visual Studio command to display the Team Explorer Build window, similar to the one for Pending Change `View.TfsPendingChanges`

Specifically I want to add a keyboard shortcut, so I can easily switch between pending changes and builds.

Even better ... is there an existing keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in shortcut - however you can define your own

[image: add your own shortcut - Here I have assigned CTRL + singleQuote]